# How does incremental refresh work? Wait type CXCONSUMER

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-2012

I have built a view (an aggregate) on a 35 billion row table, 7 years of history. Every day around 14 million rows are added. The view is used in incremental refresh in Power BI.

The table has a clustered columnstore index. And a unique, non-clustered primary key where creation-date (`CRT_DT`) is the first column. It is also partitioned on creation-date.

When I refresh today, is SQL Server then reading those 35 billion rows, aggregating them and then selecting the rows of today to pass through to Power BI?

Or is it immediately selecting only the rows of today (around 14 million), aggregating them and passing them through to Power BI?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OqqC.jpg)

Creation DateTime is `CONVERT(DATETIME2, CRT_DT)`

I am asking this for a better understanding. But also because, if I do a `SELECT` query on the 35 billion row table for a specific creation-date (whereby the `SELECT` is equal to the `SELECT` in the view) I get answer within 20 seconds.

When I refresh one day partition in Analysis Services in SSMS, the query goes to status suspended, wait type CXCONSUMER.

And stays that way for a very long time.

What is happening?

Regards

Comment: Using a function (convert) prevents the server from using the index on CRT_DT column, thus it scans the whole table.